# Terraform how to avoid resource replacement

Tags: terraform, databricks

I have this terraform code:

```
resource "databricks_dbfs_file" "this" {
  source = "${path.module}/../../../data/application_data"
  path   = format("%s/data/", local.databricks_apps_root )
}
```

but it does not work:

```
│ Error: Clean path required
│ 
│   with module.migrations.databricks_dbfs_file.this,
│   on migrations/data_migrations.tf line 14, in resource "databricks_dbfs_file" "this":
│   14:   path   = format("%s/data/", local.databricks_apps_root )
│ 
│ Replace value with /apps/data to avoid resource replacement
╵
```

How can I get the job done? The path I need to use depends on the value of `local.databricks_apps_root`, hence I can't hardcode the final path into the code.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what `local.databricks_apps_root` is set to, but one thing it _is_ clearly objecting to is the slash you added after `data`. Does it work if you remove that slash, so the format string would be `"%s/data"` instead? (I'm going to write a longer answer about ways to handle if `local.databricks_apps_root` itself contains components that need to be cleaned, but I also wanted to offer a potential simpler answer in case it happens to work for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears to be [a validation rule in the `databricks/databricks` provider](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/98c1bd9e87770f17c72a95e83c7f3e53868356da/workspace/file_resource.go#L161-L173). It's unfortunate that this is implemented as a validation rule rather than as a normalization rule; typically providers handle situations like this by accepting all forms but then treating two values as "semantically equal" if they are just two different ways to write the same information.

Hopefully the provider can change in a future version to handle this situation automatically instead, but with the provider as currently designed it seems like the requirement would be to, for example, replace `foo/../bar` with just `bar`, and other similar transformations that the Go `filepath.Clean` function does.

Since Terraform is designed to expect providers to take care of this sort of cosmetic difference in values, there isn't a built-in function that's equivalent to the "cleaning" that the provider wants you to perform, but there are some functions that do filesystem path cleaning as a side-effect of other work:

- [`abspath`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/abspath) converts a relative path into an absolute one, and "cleans" the given relative path as a side-effect while it does so.

  This option is a little problematic because using absolute paths will cause the value to differ if you check your Terraform configuration out at a different path on your computer, or on a different computer. Therefore you might need to also use `abspath(path.root)` to find the absolute form of the directory that paths would normally be relative to, and use [`trimprefix`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/trimprefix) to trim it off the path to the "apps root".

  Doing path manipulation using naive string functions is hacky and not super robust, but it might be enough to get something working here as a workaround until (hopefully) the provider can start handling this itself in a future version.
- [`dirname`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/dirname) is documented to trim the last segment from a path, on the assumption that the last segment is a filename and so the result would be the directory containing that path.

  `dirname` also "cleans" as a side-effect of its work, so you could potentially add a new meaningless component to the end of the path and ask `dirname` to trim it off, cleaning all of the other path elements at the same time:

  ```
    path = dirname(format("%s/data/PLACEHOLDER", local.databricks_apps_root ))
  ```

  In the above example I would expect `dirname` to trim off the `PLACEHOLDER` part, leaving behind a "cleaned" path that ends with the `data` segment, which should then hopefully be acceptable to the provider's validation rule.

  This approach has the advantage of using only file path manipulation functions throughout and no generic string manipulation functions, and so should therefore be more robust than the `abspath`-with-`trimprefix` option, but is also a little more obtuse in that it involves including a placeholder "filename" to trim off, which I would expect future maintainers to find confusing and so I'd definitely want to add a comment explaining what's going on.

---

I would suggest sharing this experience with the provider developers, since the provider itself is in a much better position to handle this automatically. In case it's useful to the provider developers, a typical way to handle this as a normalization rule in the legacy SDK that the provider is currently implemented with would be:

- Add a `DiffSuppressFunc` to the schema for this argument, which does the path cleaning on both the old and new values and reports a difference only if the two cleaned versions are different from one another.
- Add `DiffSuppressOnRefresh: true` to allow the `DiffSuppressFunc` to also run during the "refresh" phase, thus preventing cosmetic changes to the presentation of the path from being falsely reported as "changes outside of Terraform" (i.e. drift) in the plan.

Comment: Impressive answer! Thank you very much!